# Stuck Bottom Bracket

Tags: repair, parts, bottom-bracket

I have an 80's Fuji bike and It's definitely well past time to replace the bottom bracket. The adjusting cup came off fine, but the crank side cup is super stuck. I've tried stacking lockring washers and cranking the crap out of it. I've tried any kind of penetrating oil, almost broke my park tool for removing keyed rings. That sucker is stuck. It's been driven through a couple winters and I don't recall ever being able to remove that side.

Any ideas on how to get the crank side cup off? Is it just easier/cheaper to find the parts and rebuild it?

OH and yes I know it's reverse threaded! :D I'll be sure to grease the crud out of the new one when I can get it in.

Comment: Just to make your feel all warm and fuzzy inside, not all crank-side cups are reverse threaded.

Comment: I had one that was really stuck. Wasn't even rusted in, just really tight. A 6 foot pipe on the end of the bottom bracket wrench did the trick.

Comment: @Kibbee You must have been *really* sure which way it was threaded!

Comment: @qwertyomen You *could* just cut it out. Be careful of the threads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A 1980s Fuji should have an English bottom bracket with a left-hand threaded fixed cup.

A few methods I have used to remove very stuck bottom brackets:

1. Use the Stein Fixed Cup Wrench Clamp ([FCC-2](http://www.jastein.com/Html/Tools_for_Cranks.htm)) to secure the wrench onto the fixed cup.  This will allow you to apply more leverage without the tool slipping off.  It also allows you to pound on the tool with a mallet which sometimes helps.
2. Clamp the flats of the fixed cup in a vise and turn the frame.
3. You mentioned keyed rings - if the fixed cup does not have flats on it, you could flatten the sides with a grinder and then stick it in the vise.
4. If there's any chance that thread locking compound was used (probably not likely) then applying heat would help move it.